# How to avoid echoing a line on that last iteration of a loop?

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, conditional-statements

How do I stop the page break from echoing on the last iteration?

```
for($k=0; $k < count($selectedmonth); $k++){

    // some other code

    echo "<br pagebreak='true'>";

}
```

Comment: Why are you using a for loop when you can access the last item at `$selectedmonth[count($selectedmonth)-1]` or `end($selectedmonth)`? Why are you calculating `count($selectedmonth)` on every iteration of the loop?

Comment: i have long codes inside the for loop...i'm still learning..thank you all for the suggestion..appreciate it very much....i will try which is best for my situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare count as a variable and conditionally check it.  By setting it as a variable, you make less function calls.

```
for($k=0,$count=count($selectedmonth);$k<$count;++$k) {
    if($count!=$k+1){echo "<br pagebreak='true'>";}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$array_length = count($selectedmonth);
for($k = 0; $k < $array_length; $k++){
    if($k != $array_length - 1){
        echo '<br pagebreak="true">';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about excluding the last element from the loop?

```
 for($k=0;$k<count($selectedmonth)-1;$k++) {

    echo "<br pagebreak='true'>";

    }
```

Comment: This will not work as the OP intends to do other things in the final iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with below code without `count()` and `if()` each time.

```
$end = count($selectedmonth) - 1;
for($k = 0; $k < $end; $k++) {
    echo "<br pagebreak='true'>";
}
```

Comment: i have long codes inside the for loop...i'm still learning..thank you all for the suggestion..appreciate it very much....i will try which is best for my situation